# javascript Bubble sort problems (probably very easy)

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort, parseint

```
 <html>
 <script>
 var tal;
 var array = [];
 var element=parseIFloat(); 


 function bubbleSort(A){ 
  var swapped,
      len = A.length; 

  if(len === 1) return;

  do {
    swapped = false;
    for(var i=1;i<len;i++) {
      if(A[i-1] > A[i]) {
        var b = A[i];
        A[i] = A[i-1];
        A[i-1] = b;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  }
  while(swapped)
}


function insertnumber(){
var element=document.getElementById("element").value;  
insert (element,array);
}

function insert(element, array) {
  array.push(element);
  alert(array);
  bubbleSort(array);  
  alert(array);
}



</script>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Mata in" onclick="insertnumber()" id="resultat">
tal<input type="number" id="element" autofocus>
</body>
</html>
```

This my code but i really dont know how to get it working again, my problem is that i cant get it to read numbers correctly, trying to use "var element=parseIFloat(); " but that doesnt seem to work..

Thanks :)

Comment: you're not event using the element=parseIFloat();

Comment: You set the variable at the top but when you use it again its either used from a parameter or you reset it before you use it. For example, in the insertnumber() function, where you set it, and in the insert(element,array) function where you use the parameter. In both cases, you dont use the original

Comment: Im having extreme troubles following, so i should do? Isnt parse just a function to turn text into numbers? Am i to use parse instead of element?

Comment: what is hard to follow? you dont use the variable 'element' which you set at the start

Comment: ok maybe you should answer your question to show how you did it

Answer (score 0):

Sure,  `var element=parseIFloat();` 
was meant to be  `var element=parseFloat();` 
and put between

```
var element=document.getElementById("element").value;
```

and

```
insert (element,array);
```